# Does not operate normally without content in "validationmesses"

Tags: curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to use "GA4 Event Builder" using "curl".

Event is valid!

When I send an event using curl, if there is a problem with the parameter, the "validationMessages, fieldPath, etc." is returned.
However, when the event is valid, response is

> "{ "validationMessages": [ ] }".

> {"clientId":"1610256318","nonPersonalizedAds":false,"events":[{"name":"view_item","params":{"items":[{"item_id":"SD","item_name":"SD_solution"}],"currency":"KRW"}}]}

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); curl_close($curl); echo $response; // { "validationMessages": [ ] }
```

url `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-xxxx&api_secret=xxxx`

I think that it works well when I see it receiving a response.
However, no events occur in the Google Analytics debug view.

What is the problem?

```
$url="https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect";
$url.="?measurement_id=".$vars['measurement_id'];
$url.="&api_secret=".$vars['api_secret'];
$fields_string=json_encode($payload); // $fields_string={"clientId":"1610256318","nonPersonalizedAds":false,"events":[{"name":"view_item","params":{"items":[{"item_id":"SD","item_name":"SD_solution"}],"currency":"KRW"}}]}
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);       
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response; //{ "validationMessages": [ ] }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Theres not enough of a curl message here for me to test.

Comment: @DaImTo - I added the code to the post.